# Firebase Firestore storing data in Realtime Frestore for same collection ID

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a form which insert record with multiple values for `userID` logged in .

Whenever I am submitting a second time form, it's updating existing record rather than inserting new record .

I need to be able to insert multiple records for same `documentID(collectionID)` rather than updating existing record

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("data").document(userID);
Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
user.put("date", dates);
user.put("vehicle_number", vehicle_number);
user.put("cost", costs);
user.put("liters", liters);
user.put("fuel_type", sp);
user.put("ID", uniqueID);
 documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
      
        Toast.makeText(adding_vehicle_expense.this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.d("here2" + TAG, "onFailure: " + e.toString());
    }
});
```

Firebase
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have multiple documents directly inside another document. But it *is* possible to have a subcollection under a document, and then add multiple documents in that subcollection by calling `add()`.

E.g.

```
documentReference.collection("userdata").add(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
  ...
```